# Modification of Fords' Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

We were given a modification of Fords' algorithm that can detect negative cycles.

**Note**: $p$ is the predecessor function

> Assume that, on the current iteration, arc $wv$ is corrected. 
>   Consider the sequence $S = v, p(v), p(p(v)), . . .$ . Then
>
> • either $r$ is the last element of $S$ (and there is no negative cycle so far),
>
> • or $v$ appears in $S$ again (and a negative cycle is found).

**THE QUESTION**

Show that this modified Fords' algorithm solves the shortest path problem in
finite time by outputting either a negative cycle in $(G,c)$ or a shortest $r − v$ path for each $v ∈ V$ .

**FORDS ALGORITHM**

> We assume that at a certain iteration of the algorithm, a potential $y ∈ \Bbb R^V$ is given together with a map $p : V \setminus\text{{r}} → V$.
>
> Call an arc $vw$ incorrect if $y_w > y_v + c(vw)$.
>
> Ford’s algorithm starts with the potential $y$ and predecessor map $p$ that are given as
>   $y_r =0$, and $y_v =\infty$, $p(v)=−1$ for every $v∈V$, $v\ne r$.
>
> The element $−1$ is chosen arbitrarily. We could use any element or symbol
>   which does not belong to $V$ . Note also that $p(r)$ is undefined.
>
> The algorithm repeats the following basic step: find an incorrect arc $vw$ and correct it by setting
>   $y_w =y_v +c(vw)$, $p(w)=v$.
>
> It stops when all arcs are correct

As with all graph problems, I am not quite sure where to start with this one.

Comment: To get the ball rolling...
On the first iteration where a repeated element is detected in the sequence $w,p(w),p(p(w)),...$ the repeated element has to be $w$. Otherwise the sequence $p(w),p(p(w)),...$ that was encountered on a previous iteration would contain a repeated element. Either the root $r$ is the last element of sequence $w,p(w),p(p(w)),...$ or $w$ appears in that sequence again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question following the posting of solutions...

We only need to show that if $(G, c)$ contains a negative cycle, then the modified algorithm finds it.

We use induction on iteration $q$.

Case $q = 1$ is trivial.

Assume no negative cycle has been found up to (and including) iteration $q − 1$, and on iteration $q$ arc $wv$ was corrected, so $p(v) = w$. On the (backward) path $Q = w,p(w),p(p(w)),...$ there is no repetion (by induction) so its last element is $r$. The path $P = v,p(v),p(p(v)),...$ is the same as the (backward) path $v, w, p(w), p(p(w)), ... $unless $v$ lies on $Q$.

Thus if repetition occurs on $P$, then vertexto be repeated $v$ as $Q$ has no repeated vertices.